# How should I bind the "Save as..." option in my application if I have multiple of such options?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I'm writing an application to edit behaviour trees. The application has individual trees, but also a collection of all of the trees in our application. I have a toolbar which has two "Save as..." options: One for saving the whole collection of trees, and one for saving the current tree.

Currently, we have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> already reserved for a normal save, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> reserved for the settings menu.

I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for both of these options, but I don't think that is the best solution since having to press 4 keys for the "Save as..." option is a bit much.

So my question is: What keyboard shortcuts should I use? What is the best way to bind these to the "Save as..." buttons?

Comment: Why would someone save one tree but not the others? If you're editing multiple trees at once but only saving one, you're discarding half your work.

Comment: What operating system are you developing your app for?

Comment: Linux and windows. The current application only supports the editing of one tree

Answer (score 1):

I think the most used save as should get a more common keybind, for example Ctrl+Shift+S. For the second one, a similar shortcut should be used, which can use more keys, if and only if they are easily pressible. In this scenario i think that Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S might be a good solution. IntelliJ uses a similar approach with Ctrl+C. Copying uses Ctrl+C, Copying the path uses Ctrl+Shift+C and copy reference uses Ctrl+Shift+Alt+C.

So Ctrl+Shift+S and Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S seem appropriate to me